# What's the difference between elasticsearch plugin and elasticsearch module?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, plugins

Since both the classes in the modules subproject and plugins subproject of elasticsearch are subclass of Plugin, I am wondering  the difference between elasticsearch plugin and elasticsearch module.

For example the lang-painless module

```
public final class PainlessPlugin extends Plugin implements ScriptPlugin
```

the lang-python plugin

```
public class PythonPlugin extends Plugin implements ScriptPlugin
```

Maybe there is no difference in their implemention, the guys in elastic company put the necessary classes in module subproject and unnecessary classes in plugin subproduct. I hope one of the developer of elasticsearch can explain it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the answer from the source code of class InstallPluginCommand:

```
    /** The builtin modules, which are plugins, but cannot be installed or removed. */
    static final Set<String> MODULES;
```